# How to style a <div> already styled

Tags: html, css

I've a rule like:

```
div {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: left;
}
```

For a special `div` with a specific ID I'd like to remove the:

```
text-align:left;
```

to have the text centered, but I can't succeed.

I've added, class, id and my text do not center.
Could you please help me?

Answer (score 2):

may be .....id like that

```
#special {
         -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
         -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
         box-sizing: border-box;
         text-align : center !important;
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be abused but you can try this

```
div.new {text-align:center !important;}
```